# QFileDialog alternative that uses default file dialog defined by OS?

Tags: c++, qt

I tried using a `QFileDialog` in a program of mine, but I prefer the default file dialog that is used by the host's OS. In my case, since I use Windows 7, it should look like this:

[image: Windows' file open dialog]

Is there a way to make Qt use the default file dialog that is used by the host's OS?

---

My code:

```
QFileDialog saveDialog(this);
saveDialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptSave);

if (!saveDialog.exec())
    return;
```

Comment: What does it look like? I'm using qt 4.7.1 and when I use a QFileDialog on windows 7 it looks just like that.

Comment: @Falmair Pieter's problem, I presume, is that he is getting the legacy file dialogs on Windows.  Clearly on a non-Windows OS the dialog will not be a Windows one, but on Windows it ought to be native.  My guess is that Pieter has an older version of QT that predates the new Vista common file dialogs.

Comment: For me (on OS X though), it does like it is described in the documentation: I get the native dialogs unless I subclass QFileDialog or pass the flag DontUseNativeDialog. At least the static methods should bring up a native dialog on windows 7 though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the static functions for it and it will work.

```
QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, ... vars);
```

It will use the native dialogs for OSX and Windows, but if you don't use one of the static functions to show it, it will use the QT one.

It was written in the docs for those different static functions.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html

Comment: A "Load" dialog will then be used. What if I need a "Save" dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've [told it not to](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum), Qt tries to use the native file dialogs. If it isn't with windows7, that's a bug.

Show us some testcase code, it should be working. Are you subclassing your own QFileDialog instead of using the [builtin static method](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName)?

Comment: I'm not using the static method. I added my code to the question.

Comment: I would probably give the static method a try, if possible with your surrounding code. Unfortunately I don't have a win7 box handy to try.