# Qt and files in shared folders

Tags: qt, directory, shared, share, qfiledialog

Can I use Qt to pick/open files on shared folder?
I've tried to use QFileDialog, but it seems that there is no "network" category, as in standrd windows explorer.

Comment: I have an app that uses QFileDialog::getOpenFileName() and it does show Network in the dialog. This is in Windows 7 x64. Maybe it's a Windows configuration issue?

Comment: The same thing here, Qt 4.7.1, Windows 7 x86, works fine. There is something wrong either with the OS, or maybe because some old version of Qt is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify which version of Qt you are using. Versions 4.7+ have support for native file dialogs and use them by default. See the accepted answer here:

- [QFileDialog alternative that uses default file dialog defined by OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259994/qfiledialog-alternative-that-uses-default-file-dialog-defined-by-os)

In previous versions, there was no easy way to show network shares in the QFileDialog on Windows.