# Qt: Is there a class for shared folders?

Tags: c++, qt, samba, qt4.7

Ftp have Qftp class, but is there a class for **shared folders**? like "QSmbclient"?

My goal is to **transfer files in a shared folder automatically** (Windows or Linux setup) so QFileDialog is not advisable for me like in this thread [Qt and files in shared folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818108/qt-and-files-in-shared-folders).

My current methods:

1. Using QProcess: mount folder and paste the files (the path will be visible so I need to umount it after file is transferred).
2. Using QProcess: .sh file with smbclient command.

Is it possible to have just like in QFtp just use **connectToHost()** and **put()** functions?

If not is there a **more efficient** way of doing it?

Comment: on your typical linux/Unix machine there is `rsync` that is usually the solution for what you want, I don't think that the Qt project offers something like `rsync` in a library form, I think that you are supposed to code something like on your own if you want this kind of features programmatically or just find another C/C++ library for that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no native support for smb protocol in Qt. But you can simply use libsmbclient library instead of smbclient. Also note that libsmbclient is not thread safe so multiprocessing is required if you wish to scan a range. The following Qt project does the same:

https://github.com/adnan-kamili/ShareScanner

Comment: I think this is complicated for me because I need to remove the gui on the code and it's still using qprocess which I think would not be efficient too. Please convince me on this one.

Comment: @reggie_jimac As i mentioned the lib is not thread safe so to scan the range only option is to create multiple processes of minimal smb client written in "ip-share-scan.c" file. The "ip-share-scan.c" contains the code you are looking for.