# Accessing network folders on windows share from Scientific linux using python file_dialog()

Tags: python, linux, qt, network-drive, windows-share

Sorry, if I have just missed this, but I cannot seem to find a resolution to this problem.

I have written a small program in python 2.7 using Qt designer to deal with the graphical interface. I call file_dialog() at some point to use the OS dialog screen to locate the directory that I wish the program to write to. Here is where the problem arises:

I have a windows share drive available in nautilus: accessed through Places>Connect to server ... I can see all of the files in place through nautilus, and create and destroy files etc, but this location is not visible from the invoked file_dialog() from python. I cannot even find from the command line where the networked share is mounted.

file_dialog is a defined function:

```
def file_dialog(self):
    dir_path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self)
    return dir_path
```

Any help would be much appreciated, and sorry that this is probably something trivial.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What is `file_dialog()`? Does it use the static QFileDialog functions (which use native file dialogs), or does it use Qt's built in file dialog, or does it use something else altogether?

Comment: sorry - i realise now that would be very useful information, file_dialog is defined as:                                                                 `def file_dialog(self):
   dir_path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self)
   return dir_path `

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus uses Gnome VFS (virtual filesystem) layer, so it can access Windows (Samba) shares and other network resources like FTP or HTTP/Webdav as well as non-"classical filesystem resources" like [MTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) . This feature is implemented as a number of plugins each for a particular type of resources.

Pure Qt itself doesn't have a corresponding *portable* subsystem, but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818108/qt-and-files-in-shared-folders). If you could use KDE-specific libraries [PyKDE](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyKDE) , they also have corresponding subsystem (called [KIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KIO)) which provides functionality similar to GnomeVFS and Windows native file dialogs, see [this docs](http://api.kde.org/pykde-4.7-api/kio/KFileDialog.html)

Update: Windows and MacOSX have "standard" file dialogs, and likely you may use them as described in the aforementioned recipe. In Linux (more precisely, in X Window System, the graphical part of a typical PC-Linux installation, e.g. Ubuntu) there're no "system dialogs" at all, since every graphical toolkit (Qt, Gtk, Tk, Motif, ...) implements its own set of graphical primitives, widgets and dialogs.

KDE is built upon "Qt foundation" so functionality not implemented in pure Qt can be relatively seamlessly accessed via KDE-specific libraries, and likely this would be the most natural and fast solution. Certainly, you will need to use KFileDialog in Linux instead of QFileDialog with appropriate flags but the rest: event propagation system, widget styles etc will be shared in both Linux-specific code and "portable version".

Comment: I would like the program that this comes from to be run across OSX, linux and Windows - would using specific libraries not limit the portability here - is there another method I could invoke to find a networked folder - the networked aspect is the most important here as I am trying to create an archived drive that is accessed from many os's

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I found an easier workaround, if I manually (from the terminal) mount the drive (with mount.cifs) to a known folder on the linux system then the QFileDialog has no problem interacting with it at all. It is only a problem if the drive is mounted through the GUI.